# Finding the Probability of a random variable with countably infinite values

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

So I was working on a problem where I am provided with a PMF $p_X(k)= c/3^k$ for $k=1,2,3....$
I was able to calculate $c$ using the basic property of PMF and it came to be 2. I am not able to solve the next part which states that "Find $P(X\ge k)$ for all $k=1,2,3......$.

Any suggestions?

P.S :Here is the actual question:

Let X be a discrete random variable with probability mass function $p_X(k) = c/3^k$
for k = 1, 2, ... for some
$c > 0$. Find $c$. Find $P(X\ge k)$ for all $k = 1, 2,3....$

Comment: Maybe calculate $P(X < k)$ using geometric series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Any specific formulas?

Comment: Yes the series sums to  1-(1-1/r) for which in your case has r=3. The constant c is the normalizing factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, $$S=\frac{2}{3}+\cdots+\frac{2}{3^{k-2}}+\frac{2}{3^{k-1}}$$

multiply $S$ by $\frac{1}{3}.$ Thus,

$$\frac{1}{3}S=\frac{2}{3^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{2}{3^{k-1}}+\frac{2}{3^{k}}.$$

Subtract $S$ of $\frac{1}{3}S,$

$$\frac{2}{3}S=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3^{k}}.$$ Thus,

$$S=1-\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}.$$ Now,

if $k=1, P(X\geq k)=1,$ and if $k>1,$

\begin{eqnarray}
P(X\geq k)&=&1-P(X< k)\\
&=&1-P(X\leq k-1)\\
&=&1-\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{2}{3^{n}}\\
&=&1-(1-\frac{1}{3^{k-1}})\\
&=&\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}
\end{eqnarray}